# Is there any way of knowing if a method is being run from within a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I'm interested in being able to determine whether or not a class method is being executed within the class itself or from outside, and having different functionality based that.

What's a way of determining whether or not a class method is being executed within the class itself?

This is a quick and dirty example of what I'm interested in:

```
class Example {
    internal = false
    meow () {
        console.log(this.internal);
        return 'meow'
    }
    makeSound () {
       return this.meow.bind({...this, internal: true})();
    }
}

const example = new Example();
console.log(example.meow())
console.log(example.makeSound())
```

Here, `Example#meow` runs two times, one from within `Example#makeSound` and once on it's own. I would like a way of knowing from within `Example#meow` when the method has been executed from within the class, versus from outside the class, as in `example.meow()`.

One way to do this, is with binding all internal calls to methods, if I add a property `internal` true, to this bound copy of `this`, then I can check from within `Example#meow` where the call is coming from.

This is only a proof of concept, but it's not great to try and clone this, and seems to be a real pain.

Comment: `console.log()` in the method?

Comment: @JaromandaX hey, what?

Comment: You asked *What's a way of determining whether or not a class method is being executed* I answered *put `console.log` in the method*

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with your solution.

Comment: Not sure there is an easy way to check this. Methods don't retain a link to their instance. Well, methods don't usually exist on an instance anyway but on the prototype. Your way of handling it is probably the closest you can get - any sort of check for the situation you're after will need to *somehow* compare `this` to existing instances.

Comment: This is either an XY problem or code smell. You're implementing the class, so you have full knowledge over if, when and where you call which of your own methods. If you need different behavior from a method, call a different method. Make it private and it cannot be called externally.

Comment: @IngoBürk I think you nailed it here, I think as much as it's a pain I may just need to have a `private _action` be referenced by a `action` method. I guess I was trying to eliminate some clutter, but there's value in being more declarative.